# Which function will be called when QEMU write the data to normal ram page

Tags: qemu

As stated in the title, how can I collect the data when memory is accessed?
I have done some modification in the function `cpu_physical_memory_rw`
but it does not work.

Answer (score 2):

There is no single place where you can intercept all writes to guest RAM, because for speed reasons QEMU's fast path code for RAM access involves directly generated x86 instructions which load the data from the host memory which has been assigned as guest RAM, and execution doesn't come out to a C function at all. QEMU is designed for speed, not ease of instrumentation.

Comment: So how can I collect data trace? plz help me